# SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

I have a problem trying to send some data from a table that I made, I get an error, it says that the update I am doing to the database is correct but the fields are not updated and it sends me this error

```
parsererror
SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at n.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
    at vc (jquery.min.js:4)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

I really don't know what this error was because when I click on the send button I get this error and the fields are not updated ... this is the scrip I have

```
 <script>
  function viewData(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '../A30.php?p=view',
      method: 'GET',
    }).done(function(data){
      $('tbody').html(data)
      tableData()
    })
  }
  function tableData(){
    $('#tabledit').Tabledit({
      url:'../A30.php',
      eventType: 'dblclick',
      editButton : true, 
      deleteButton : false,
       columns:{
              identifier:[0,'ID'],
              editable: [[0,'ID'],[1, 'Empleado'],[5,'Monto']]
      },
      buttons:{
      style: 'width:150px;',
        edit:{
          class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success' ,
          html: '<span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" ></span> Editar',
          action: 'edit'
        },
        delete:{
          class: 'btn btn-sm btn-default',
          html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Trash',
          action: 'delete'
        },
        save:{
          class: 'btn btn-sm btn-info',
          html: '<span class="fa fa-floppy-o  "></span> Guardar'
        },
        restore:{
          class: 'btn btn-sm btn-warning',
          html: 'Restore',
          action: 'restore'
        },
        confirm:{
          class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger',
          html: 'Confirm'
        },
      },
      onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        viewData()
      },
      onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow){
        console.log('onFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow)');
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrow);
      },
      onAjax: function(action, serialize){
        console.log ('onAjax(action, serialize)');
        console.log(action);
        console.log(serialize);
      }
    });
  }
  </script>
```

here I have the code in php where I receive the variables to send it to my database but it is not sent it only tells me that it has been inserted successfully but in the database they were not updated

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

    if ($input['action'] === 'edit') {
            $actualizar ="UPDATE sysnom_nomina_det_tmp SET monto='".$input['Monto']."' where ID='".$input['ID']."' AND empleado = '".$input['Empleado']."' AND monto = '".$input['Monto']."' ";
            $resul = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $actualizar);
              if(!$resul){
                echo "Error al Actualizar";
                echo $actualizar;
                echo $resul;
              } else {
                echo "Insertado exitosamente......";
                echo $resul;
              }

        }
  sqlsrv_close($resul);
    echo json_encode($input);
}
```

I would really appreciate it if you can help me since I don't know what I have wrong

Comment: You really need to learn about prepared/parametrised statements. This is wide open to injection

Comment: but how could I solve it

Answer (score 0):

You must use json_encode function for all outputs(also error messages).
try this version :

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
    $respone = [
        "message"=>"",
        "data"=>[]
    ];
    if ($input['action'] === 'edit') {
        $actualizar ="UPDATE sysnom_nomina_det_tmp SET monto='".$input['Monto']."' where ID='".$input['ID']."' AND empleado = '".$input['Empleado']."' AND monto = '".$input['Monto']."' ";
        // you can use prepeared statetments for sql injection threats
        $resul = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $actualizar);
        $response["data"]["result"] = $resul;
        if(!$resul)                                        
            $respone["message"] = "Error al Actualizar";
        else
            $respone["message"] = "Insertado exitosamente......";
    }
    sqlsrv_close($resul);
    $response["data"]["query"] = $actualizar;        
    $response["data"]["input"] = $input;
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Comment: where could I use that to know where I have the error

Comment: If you expect json response you must use it for all outputs (echo). Actually you can inspect devtools and watch network for response. This is js error acepting response from backend. I added screenshot : https://ibb.co/Kw4NHGm

Comment: it doesn't appear to me like that

Comment: _A30.php_ click on it and see response.

Comment: It makes me an error when using the code that you passed me

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 POST http://192.168.30.216/nomina/A30.php?p=view 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
viewData @ A30.html:134
onload @ A30.html:84

Comment: may be you can remove php tags from start and end of file.(i updated answer)

Comment: Well, it keeps marking me the same error I am going to send you the whole code of that window as I have it for you to look

Comment: para que es ese link

Comment: okay, i fixed my error,sorry for that. (updated answer  try it now)

Comment: esto donde lo utilizaria : JSON.stringify (ur_object aquí)

Comment: the only thing I need is for the changes to be reflected in the database if the fields are updated because they are not doing it but I don't know what could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    require ('recursos/conexion.php');



    $page = isset($_GET['p'])? $_GET['p'] : ''
;   if ($page=='view') {

        $sql = "exec sp_sys_nom_autoriza2 'A30',1";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sql);
      $select =  "select * from sysnom_nomina_det_tmp where suc = 'A30'";
      $stm = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $select);
        $totalVU = sqlsrv_num_rows($stm);     
       while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stm, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

         if ($row['notas'] !== "AHORRO" ) {
              if ($row['notas'] !== "PRESTAMO DE AHORRO") {
         ?>
        <tr  style="width:1900px" >

          <td style="width:141px;"><?php echo $row["ID"]?>     </td>
          <td style="width:141px;"><?php echo $row["empleado"]?></td>
          <td style="width:141px;"><?php echo $row["nombre"]?>  </td>
          <td style="width:141px;"><?php echo $row["depto"]?>   </td>
          <td style="width:141px;"><?php echo $row["percepcion"]?></td>
          <td style="width:141px;"><?php echo $row["monto"]?></td>
          <td style="width:141px;"><?php echo $row["notas"]?>   </td>
<?php
          $autorizar = rtrim($row['autorizar']);
           if ($autorizar == 1) {
                      echo "<td id='autorizar'><input type ='checkbox' name='checkbox' id='checkbox' value='1' style='width:30px; height:30px;' checked></td>";

                      }else{
                         echo "<td id='autorizar'><input type ='checkbox' name='checkbox' id='checkbox' value='1' style='width:30px; height:30px;'></td>";
                      }

    }  
  }
}
}else{

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
    $respone = [
        "message"=>"",
        "data"=>[]
    ];
    if ($input['action'] === 'edit') {
        $actualizar ="UPDATE sysnom_nomina_det_tmp SET monto='".$input['Monto']."' where ID='".$input['ID']."' AND empleado = '".$input['Empleado']."' AND monto = '".$input['Monto']."' ";
        // you can use prepeared statetments for sql injection threats
        $resul = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $actualizar);
        if(!$resul)                                        
            $respone["message"] = "Error al Actualizar";
        else
            $respone["message"] = "Insertado exitosamente......";
    }
    sqlsrv_close($resul);
    $response["data"]["query"] = $actualizar;
    $response["data"]["result"] = $resul;
    $response["data"]["input"] = $input;
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you send the your json as string. use

> JSON.stringify(ur_object here)